# Multiple Line Insert Query Issue Looking for More Efficient Way

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, ssis, insert

I have created a SQL Server database table and have many data entries to enter into the table. In this particular scenario I have two columns, `Technology Questions` and `time_entered`.

I have tried to combine the existing data values into a single `INSERT INTO` statement, however I have not been able to find a way to scale it up so I don't have spend all day copying over basic data.

This query works however note that it has only 4 data elements, two for each column. I'd like to scale this up so I can insert hundreds of lines at once.  The insert statement below I derived from the existing data below (from a SQLITE3 table and I am trying to insert the data into a SQL Server database).

```
INSERT INTO questiontype([Technology Questions], time_entered)
VALUES ('Technology Question', '2018-10-29 13:31'),
       ('Technology Question', '2018-10-29 14:11')
```

The above example works great but I don't know the best way to scale this up.

Example of existing data (There are hundreds of rows like below)

```
Technology Question|2019-03-23 10:40
Technology Question|2019-03-23 10:40
Technology Question|2019-03-23 13:24
Technology Question|2019-03-23 13:55
Technology Question|2019-03-23 13:55
Technology Question|2019-03-23 16:23
Technology Question|2019-03-23 16:26
Technology Question|2019-03-23 16:59
Technology Question|2019-03-24 13:34
Technology Question|2019-03-24 15:11
```

Is there a more efficient way by chance?

Comment: Look at the example of an insert using `SELECT` rather than `VALUES` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### (1) Linked Server approach

Since you are reading data from SQLite3, you can create a linked server from SQL Server and use a simple insert statement to import data:

```
INSERT INTO questiontype([Technology Questions], time_entered)
SELECT [Technology Questions], time_entered
FROM openquery(sqlite_linked_server, 'select * from sqlitetable')
```

**Additional information**

- [Creating a SQL Server Linked Server to SQLite to Import Data](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3087/creating-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-sqlite-to-import-data/)

---

### (2) SSIS approach

If you are familiar with SQL Server integration Services, it is an efficient way to transfer data from a data source to another, you can use it to transfer data from SQLite through ODBC into SQL Server.

- [CONNECTING TO SQLITE THROUGH SSIS](https://rainydaycode.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/connecting-to-sqlite-through-ssis/)

---

### (3) Using ad-hoc query approach

*I haven't tried this approach before, i don't know if it is efficient or not.*

You can connect to SQLite database through ODBC without adding a linked server, you can do this using an ad-hoc query using `OPENROWSET`

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

INSERT INTO questiontype([Technology Questions], time_entered)
SELECT [Technology Questions], time_entered
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'DSN=<odbc DSN>', 
  'SELECT * FROM sqliteTable')
```

**Additional information**

- [Import data from SQLite to Microsoft SQL Server](http://pavel.surmenok.com/2015/07/19/import-data-from-sqlite-to-microsoft-sql-server/)